# Mockk match overloaded function with generics

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk

So I have 2 overloaded `score` functions, one of which takes a `performance` param of type `Performance`, and the other which takes a `performances` param, which is a `List<Performance>`. The former returns a double, while the latter returns a double array. (Another team owns the `Scorer` class, so fixing it to not overload like this isn't really doable rn; breaking changes and all).

I want to test 2 branches, one with each implementation, how can I mock these using kotlin's [mockk](https://mockk.io/)?

The former can be mockked using `ofType(Performance::class)`,

```
scorer: Scorer = mockk()
every { scorer.score(????) } returns doubleArrayOf(0.9)
```

What goes there?

`ofType(List<Performance>::class)` doesn't work because apparently that can't be done with generics.

`not(ofType(CandidateFeature::class))` results in a compile-time error `Type mismatch: inferred type is DoubleArray but Double was expected`

How do I explicitly choose which overriden signature I'm trying to call?

Comment: `scorer.score(any<List<Performance>>()) `, `scorer.score(ofType<List<Performance>>())`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
every { any<Performance>() } returns doubleArrayOf(0.9)
```

Using any<Performance>() will cause it to know which one to mock.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **withArg**

```
every { scorer.score(withArg<Performance> {} ) returns mockData
every { scorer.score(withArg<List<Performance>> {} ) returns mockData
```

Comment: `withArg` doesnt seem to be a mockk function

Comment: This doesn't work for mockk

Comment: @Siavash See Matchers section in https://mockk.io/  (... available in verification mode only )
Try to use an updated version